# mysql:show all value of three fields

Tags: mysql

i have a question...
i have a DB..i'm just want to show all value of 3 fields from DB,they are Line,Model,and NIK...
i want it order by insp_datetime field...and descending..limit 0,30..

i've been try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Inspection_report
WHERE NIK='".$NIK."' AND Line='".$Line."' AND Model='".$Model."'
ORDER BY Insp_datetime DESC
LIMIT 0,30;
```

But i think it's wrong..can you give me the correct code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think what you want is:

```
SELECT NIK, Line, Model FROM Inspection_report 
   ORDER BY Insp_datetime DESC LIMIT 0,30;
```

which will give you the NIK, Line, and Model of the most recent 30 inspections.